# Как получить данные из string файла?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Честное слово, гуглил как только можно, но ответа так и не нашел. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, все-таки очень простой вопрос.

```
<string-array name="questions">
    <item>Сыр</item>
    <item>Замок</item>
    <item>Гора</item>
    <item>Возможность</item>
</string-array>
```

Хочу достать этот список в классе MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val items: List<String> = this.resources.getStringArray(R.array.questions).toList()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!